# sending file from Java to c# exception found

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I try to send a java application file to a .Net application (c #) using a socket. Here is what I did Java (server side)

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1592);
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection accepted from " + socket);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                File file = new File("C:\\test.txt");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                out.println(file.length());
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                byte[] bytes  = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                bis.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                os.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

C#(client)

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
              tcpClient.Connect(ip, 1592);

                using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                using (var output = File.Create("result.txt"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client connected. Starting to receive the file");

                    // read the file in chunks of 1KB
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)//(Exception caught here)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
```

I had an exception in the specified line containing the following problem

```
Additional information: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant.
```

Please any help , i've been facing the issue since few days , and i could not figure it out .
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Client is running, but the service is not available. (stopped, crashed..). Perhaps, the Firewall block the connection

- Verify that the firwall not blocking your server
- You must debug you code and verify its behavior (exception, etc..)

regards

Comment: exactly that's what i did, actually when debugging every thing is ok.Any help please . Thanks

Comment: have you tested your Firewall ?

Comment: @aelbouchari i guess it is an issue of Firewall , because when i put 127.0.0.1 as ip address, i do not get any exception , would you please try the code i gave you ,Thanks

Comment: @MaherHTB  I'll do it, give me some time ;)

Comment: Thank you , am waiting , so kind of you.